# Gorilla Sessions Break in App Engine SDK version 1.9.62

Tags: google-app-engine, session, go, gorilla

My unit tests for my API endpoints that checks for authentication via *Gorilla Sessions* fail when using the latest version of the App Engine SDK. i.e.

```
// app.go
session, _ := store.Get(req, "login")
_, has := session.Values["userID"] //value is set in app_test.go
// has == false for v1.9.62 onwards, has == true for 1.9.57 and earlier
```

When I switch back to either 1.9.54 or 1.9.57, the tests pass. Nothing was changed in the source code, only the version of the SDK.

I'm using App Engine SDK version 1.9.63 (the App Engine SDK, not the Cloud SDK) with Gorilla Sessions (latest version).

Does anyone has any knowledge about version 1.9.6x of the App Engine SDK breaking Gorilla Sessions?

P.S. Although the download page says the version 1.9.61 (and the downloaded zip file says likewise as well), when running the SDK, it reports as 1.9.63.

`$ goapp version
go version 1.8.3 (appengine-1.9.63) linux/amd64`

Comment: What exactly is broken? I'm heating some weird bug with losing inserts that's done in cross-group transactions. Had not chance to create a minimized reproducible example and to fail a bug yet.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear. The session value that I set in the test could not be read from in the function handler. (Edited the original question with an example.)

Comment: What storage do you use to store sessions? cookies/datastore?

Comment: Cookies. `store := sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("secret"))`

Comment: I found some that with `go version 1.8.5 (appengine-1.9.65)` the `req` variable that represents the request has a different pointer address in the tests than what it has when passed to the middleware layer checking the user credentials.

With `go version 1.6.4 (appengine-1.9.54)`, the request has the same pointer address in both the tests and the middleware. I think that is causing the tests to fail, but I don't know the solution to it.

Comment: I've seen an open issue about this either on AppEngine or Gorilla repo.

Comment: Check this issue: https://github.com/golang/appengine/issues/99

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderTrakhimenok for the reply. Yes, the issue seems related. Unfortunately, after looking through the issue and the source code, I'm still not sure of how to work around this specific issue of mine.

Comment: After some more investigation, I think it has to do with Gorilla MUX using the `contextSet()` selectively. Version 1.9.54 of the SDK is based on Go 1.6 which causes the `contextSet()` function from "context_gorilla.go" to be used. Version 1.9.65 of the SDK is based on Go 1.8 which causes the `contextSet()` function from "context_native.go" to be used. Unfortunately, I know the cause of the problem but not the solution :(

Comment: Filed an issue with [Mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux/issues/352) with sample code to reproduce the issue.